# How to consume/deserialize .Net WCF service JSON response in Java

Tags: java, c#, json, wcf, serialization

I am having problem while consuming/deserializing WCF .NET JSON response in Java. JSON response is in the following format.

```
{"d":"[
{\"ID\":123,\"Company\":\"Microsoft\",\"Country\":\"USA\",
\"website\":\"http:\/\/www.microsoft.com\",
\"FirstName\":\"john\",\"Email\":\"abc@gmail.com\"},

{\"ID\":124,\"Company\":\"Google\",\"Country\":\"USA\",
\"website\":\"http:\/\/www.google.com\",
\"FirstName\":\"john\",\"Email\":\"abc@gmail.com\"},

{\"ID\":125,\"Company\":\"Apple\",\"Country\":\"USA\",
\"website\":\"http:\/\/www.abc.com\",
\"FirstName\":\"john\",\"Email\":\"abc@gmail.com\"}
]"}
```

While on the Java code side I am having problem to deserialize this json response to get out my objects and their corresponding properties.

This is the java code currently I am using to deserialize json response.

```
String companyTitle = "";
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement element = parser.parse(jsonResponseString);
if (element.isJsonObject()) {
JsonArray companies = element.getAsJsonArray();
JsonObject company = companies.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
companyTitle = company .get("Company").getAsString();     
}
```

Is there any problem in the JSON response format or its right? any kind of help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't emphasise absolutely everything. It's ugly, and useless.

Comment: What do you mean sir??

Comment: you didn't mentioned where you find error in your code!!

Comment: When this line is being executed i get my program crashed
JsonObject company = companies.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
thanks for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're getting that response - it't not valid json. There are two things wrong with it

1. The outer square brackets should not be wrapped in quotes.
2. The quote escape characters need to be removed (not sure if this is just you putting them in?)

Without you posting the actual error you get (hint: even though stack overflow is powerful, we have not yet developed the ability to read minds) it's very difficult to know what the actual problem is.

Comment: thanks @Tom for the help and pointing out my error, yes the response i am getting is in the wrong format now first i am making my json response correct then may be issue will be resolved

Answer (score 1):

Tom is right. Valid JSON should look like this:

```
{"d":[
    {"ID":123,"Company":"Microsoft","Country":"USA",
    "website":"http://www.microsoft.com",
    "FirstName":"john","Email":"abc@gmail.com"},

    {"ID":124,"Company":"Google","Country":"USA",
    "website":"http://www.google.com",
    "FirstName":"john","Email":"abc@gmail.com"},

    {"ID":125,"Company":"Apple","Country":"USA",
    "website":"http://www.aabc.com",
    "FirstName":"john","Email":"abc@gmail.com"}
]}
```

And your code like this:

```
String companyTitle = "";
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement element = parser.parse(jsonResponseString);
JsonObject object = element.getAsJsonObject();
if (object.isJsonObject()) {
    JsonArray companies = object.getAsJsonArray("d");
    JsonObject company = companies.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
    companyTitle = company .get("Company").getAsString();     
}
```